# Elliptic curves: twists and homogeneous spaces

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have a slight confusion with these 2 concepts. It is my understanding that twists of an elliptic curve $E/k$ are elliptic curves $E'/k$ with $j(E)=j(E')$.

Then in Chapter X of The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Silverman introduces principal homogeneous spaces for $E/K$ as smooth curves $C/K$ together with the transitive algebraic group action. He proceeds to prove that these curves are in fact twists of $E/k$. However he keeps using the notation $C$ throughout the rest of the chapter, which I interpret as "this isn't necessarily an elliptic curve".

I believe this has to do with the fact that $C$ might not have $k$-rational points.What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  $C/K$ is a curve defined over $K$, but it might not have $K$-rational points.

However, because $C/K$ is a twist of $E/K$, then $E/K$ and $C/K$ are isomorphic over $\overline{K}$ (algebraic closure of $K$).  The curve $C/K$, of course, has $\overline{K}$-rational points.

Comment: OK, so then the way I stated the definition of twists for elliptic curves is incorrect and that was the source of my confusion.